# bind9 geoip does not function correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, geoip

**bind9** `bind-9.17.2` has been compiled from source on **debian-9**.

```
./named -V
BIND 9.17.2 (Development Release) <id:6d46544>
running on Linux x86_64 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07)
built by make with  '--with-maxminddb' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-fixed-rrset' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind'
compiled by GCC 6.3.0 20170516
compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
compiled with zlib version: 1.2.8
linked to zlib version: 1.2.8
linked to maxminddb version: 1.2.0
threads support is enabled

default paths:
  named configuration:  /etc/bind/named.conf
  rndc configuration:   /etc/bind/rndc.conf
  DNSSEC root key:      /etc/bind/bind.keys
  nsupdate session key: /usr/var/run/named/session.key
  named PID file:       /usr/var/run/named/named.pid
  named lock file:      /usr/var/run/named/named.lock
  geoip-directory:      /usr/share/GeoIP
```

The main goal is use its **GeoIP** feature and answering queries based on resolver(s) IP address location and the configuration for `named.conf.local` is as simple as this :

```
...
...
include "/etc/bind/geoip/GeoIP.acl";

view "Iran" {
      match-clients { IR; };
      recursion no;
      zone "ppod.ir" {
            type master;
            file "/etc/bind/db.ppod.ir.iran";
      };
};

view "default"  {
       include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
       ...
       ...
```

The zone for `db.ppod.ir.iran` is:

```
; A, AAAA => host record
ppod.ir.     1      IN      A       185.8.172.233
```

and for the `default view` is:

```
; A, AAAA => host record
ppod.ir.     1      IN      A       5.63.13.22
ppod.ir.     1      IN      A       95.216.12.6
```

---

Now if I query the domain **ppod.ir** from Iran, the DNS server gives me wrong IPs.

```
$ dig ppod.ir # the answer is wrong

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> ppod.ir
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15519
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ppod.ir.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ppod.ir.        1   IN  A   5.63.13.22
ppod.ir.        1   IN  A   95.216.12.6

;; Query time: 263 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 14 12:59:53 +0430 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

but either ways if I ask the DNS server directly or trace the query it gives the right IP.

```
$ dig ppod.ir @171.22.25.82 +short # the answer is right
185.8.172.233
```

and tracing it:

```
$ dig ppod.ir @1.1.1.1 +trace  +short # the answer is right
NS a.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS b.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS c.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS d.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS e.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS f.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS g.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS h.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS i.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS j.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS k.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS l.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
NS m.root-servers.net. from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
RRSIG NS 8 0 ..... from server 1.1.1.1 in 257 ms.
couldn't get address for 'ns2.redcursor.ir': not found
A 185.8.172.233 from server 171.22.25.82 in 40 ms.
```

The cache for TTL has been set to 1, also bind has been complied with GeoIP feature, and question is **why does not DNS server response correctly**?
*I know about caching IP address and recursive queries of public-dns-servers, but based on what I configured the IPs should be cached*

here is the log for these two queries `dig ppod.ir` and `dig ppod.ir @171.22.25.82` from the same location and IP address. the first one is wrong, the second one is right.

```
14-Jul-2020 08:38:21.312 info: client @0x7fbb20000a30 162.158.82.125#56703 (ppod.ir): view default: query: ppod.ir IN A -E(0)D (171.22.25.82)
14-Jul-2020 08:38:21.312 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 162.158.82.125#56703 (ppod.ir): view default: query 'ppod.ir/A/IN' approved
14-Jul-2020 08:38:21.312 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 162.158.82.125#56703 (ppod.ir): view default: reset client
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509: UDP request
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 5: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509: view Iran: using view 'Iran'
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509: view Iran: request is not signed
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509: view Iran: recursion not available
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 info: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509 (ppod.ir): view Iran: query: ppod.ir IN A +E(0)K (171.22.25.82)
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509 (ppod.ir): view Iran: query 'ppod.ir/A/IN' approved
14-Jul-2020 08:38:43.308 debug 3: client @0x7fbb20000a30 5.117.5.210#55509 (ppod.ir): view Iran: reset client
```

Comment: You seem to be using a local stub resolver (e.g. systemd-resolved). Is it configured to query DNS servers which are in Iran? If it sends DNS queries to servers in another country, that might cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  yes I am using `systemd-resovle` and CF DNS servers `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1`. also I suspected them and changed them but still the response was wrong. I noticed that [CloudFlare DNS server does not send](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/1-1-1-1-prevents-geoip-based-dns-lookups-from-working/173272) the actual user IP address. Maybe it is the issue that public DNS servers do not send actual IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelHampton that pointed out this fact that my local resolver has been configured to use a DNS server our side of the network that I had set up bind9 DNS server.
So after not configuration my local resolver using `systemd-resolver` and enabling `DHCP` of my modem, now a query from `dig` gives the right answer.

```
dig ppod.ir

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> ppod.ir
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21503
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ppod.ir.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ppod.ir.        1   IN  A   185.8.172.233

;; Query time: 153 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 19 12:14:46 +0430 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```